# Spring TestRestTemplate authentication

Tags: authentication, testing, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am trying to build Spring Boot test to test rest API, so that I can get Principal from the request and use that to identify the user.
Server returns

> {"timestamp":1502014507361,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access
>   Denied","path":"/hello"}

What am I missing here?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RestTemplateTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testit() {

        testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("user", "password");
        String responsePayload = testRestTemplate.getForObject("/hello", String.class);
    }



@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String heipat(Principal principal) {
        String string = "hello there";
        return string;
    }



    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticated first. like requesting a `/login` API. 
Also you need to make the login API accessible by everyone by doing this:

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
```

When you includes `WebSecurityConfig` you will have basic usernamerAndPassowrd authentication.

Comment: Doesn't help. Still something missing?

Comment: the API `/hello` is not reachable until you are logged in. So you need to authenticate your self first, then send the request. or make the API accessible for public using `.antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()`